# preview загруженного файла на python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, flask

Как реализовать preview загруженного файла на python, flask? Я могу получать только имя файла, а мне нужен сам файл, картинка, pdf док и т.д

`html:`

Select Document

```
my file is: {{ file }}
```

`python:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    file = request.form['file']
    print(file)
return render_template('profile.html',file=file)
```